# Electron ipcMain & ipcRenderer fail to communicate with each other

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

I'm writing a desktop app with electron js and I wanna both send data from my main process to my renderer process and the other way around. For that I'm using the `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer`, yet weirdly enough, while being able to send data via my renderer with `ipcRenderer.send()`, I cannot receive any data from my main process with `ipcRenderer.on()`. It just doesn't work for some reason.

Afterwards I tried to find the bug by writing a test, following electron's documentation. The test however doesn't work at all, since neither process seems able to send something to the other process. This is the code that I wrote for my test:

**main.js**:

```
const { app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

const createWin = async () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        },
    });
    win.loadFile('./index.html');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
            resolve();
        });
    });
};

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
    const win = await createWin();
    console.log('Ready to show');

    ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
        console.log(arg); // prints "ping"
        event.reply('asynchronous-reply', 'pong');
    });

    ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
        console.log(arg); // prints "ping"
        event.returnValue = 'pong';
    });
});
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test, please work</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="./app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')); // prints "pong"

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg); // prints "pong"
});
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping');
```

Here's what the Renderer logs:

```
{ error: "reply was never sent" }
```

Here's the link to the documentation where I have the code from:  https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages

Comment: I don't see where "reply was never sent" is being logged. Is that something from Electron

Comment: so you can't break in the async message handler?

Comment: The Error message is being logged in the Browser Window. How could I break into the async message handler? @pushkin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're hooking up your event handlers too late.

You're only adding `ipcMain.on` after the page has loaded and `ready-to-show` has fired. You should either set them up earlier, like before you create the window, or just remove the `await` in `await createWin()`.

For reference, Electron throws the error [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/da8c35e3b256b4f9ad0c16edfbc2b56748b3a740/shell/browser/api/event.cc#L29)